# Update textView text from class companion object

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I'm trying to update a textView from a class's companion object and the application crashes. What am I doing wrong?

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.test.testapp.classes.ExampleClass
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        testMessage.text = "1"
        ExampleClass.writeText("2")
    }
}
```

**ExampleClass.kt**

```
import com.test.testapp.MainActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class ExampleClass {
    companion object{
        fun writeText(textValue:String) {
            MainActivity().testMessage.text = textValue
        }
    }
}
```

**Android studio error message:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.test.testapp, PID: 15819
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.testapp/com.test.testapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: May be you are looking for a view that does not belongs to the current activity's view hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because with the code `MainActivity()...` you aren't getting the Activity that has been loaded, but you are constructing a new Activity that hasn't been shown yet so the view doesn't exist.

There are various ways to achieve what you want, even if the flow is wrong

example

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        testMessage.text = "1"
        ExampleClass.writeText("2",this)
    }
}

class ExampleClass {
    companion object{
        fun writeText(textValue:String,mainActivity:MainActivity) {
            mainActivity.testMessage.text = textValue
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know exactly why do you want to do that but if you want to pass data between activities or fragments or services check that     https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

Comment: This seems true but you should check that is activity still alive. Otherwise you could get exception. You can use "mainActivity.isFinishing" to check that.

Comment: you could do a lot of things, it isn't something that you should do, it is just an example

Answer (score 1):

inside the **writeText (textValue: String)** method, you create a **new instance** of MainActivity (MainActivity()) in **which textView is null**, and not get the existing one

you should not use companion object for this.
Сould explain the situation, why do you need it

if it **necessary**, you can do so:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.test.testapp.classes.ExampleClass
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        testMessage.text = "1"
        ExampleClass.writeText("2", testMessage)
    }
}
```

ExampleClass.kt

```
import com.test.testapp.MainActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class ExampleClass {
    companion object{
        fun writeText(textValue:String, textView: TextView) {
            textView.text = textValue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Pass `MainActivity Object` to `ExampleClass`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        testMessage.text = "1"
        ExampleClass.writeText("2",this)
    }
}
```

And use `MainActivity object` to access its properties.

```
class ExampleClass {
    companion object{
        fun writeText(textValue:String,mainActivity: MainActivity) {
            mainActivity.testMessage.text = textValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why `writeText(textValue:String,context: Context)` and then cast instead of `writeText(textValue:String, mainActivity: MainActivity)` ??